# Подключиться к удалённому mysql в терминале Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, bash, mysql

Ошибка при подключении к удалённой БД mysql. Пытаюсь соединиться в Ubuntu через консольную утилиту "mysql". В перспективе нужно соединиться через bash скрипт.

команда:

```
mysql -h %host% -u %user% -p %password% %dbname%
```

вывод:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '%user%'@'%ip%' (using password: YES)
```

Скрипт вставки данных:

```
content=$ztag1
xhost="%server%"
xuser="%user%"
xpass="%pass%"
xdb="%dbname%"
mysql --host=$xhost --user=$xuser --password=$xpass $xdb << EOF
insert into table (cms_content) values('30','1','1','2014-02-10 17:49:00','2014-02-10','0','title','description','$content','1','1','0','meta_desc','meta_keys','0','0','0','0','1','6','1','','0','pagetitle','','com_content_read.tpl');
EOF
```

Ответ тот же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это значит, что в конфигурации той самой базы не разрешено подключаться к этой базе этому пользователю с данного IP (скорее всего, доступ для этого пользователя открыт только для подключения с localhost - самая распространенная причина by default).

Непосредственно на удаленной базе (с локального хоста или же удаленно тем пользователем, кто имеет возможность 'раздавать' привилегии другим пользователям), как вариант, надо прибегнуть к:

```
GRANT ALL ON ваша-база.таблица TO 'здесь-пользователь'@'здесь-ваш-IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'здесь-пароль' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

- Используйте ALL только в том случае,
     если даете все привилегии, если нет -
     то выборочно, через запятую: например
     SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE и т.д.
- Если на месте 'здесь-ваш-IP' подставить '%', то подключение станет возможным с любого IP, что не рекомендуется.
- Используйте 'WITH GRANT OPTION', если хотите дать возможность, в свою очередь, предоставить эту привилегию к той же таблице, с или без GRANT OPTION, любому другому пользователю.

Comment: действительно оказалось, что пользователю можно было подключаться исключительно с адреса localhost.

Comment: Да, как правило, это установки по умолчанию.